# Why AlertDialog 'flickers' while it is being build?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-alertdialog

I have a *very* simple AlertDialog with a WebView as `view` that loads a LOCAL html file 'page' in the assets (code below). The problem I have is that I can see it being 'build' while it opens for a fraction of a second: first the title in a small dialog window in the center of the screen, then the dialog gets bigger with the text, etc. It's an annoying behaviour. The other windows open nicely.

Is this a normal behaviour? Maybe it's the WebView? Is there any way to tell the AlertDialog: "build the dialog BEFORE showing it"?

Thanks!!

The dialog code:

```
@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
public static void viewHTML(Context context, String page) {

    WebView myMsg = new WebView(context);
    myMsg.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myMsg.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + page);
    myMsg.setBackgroundColor(0);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setView(myMsg);
    builder.setTitle("sometitle");
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

*EDIT*

Actually, my code also uses an animation for the AlertDialog (it enters from the left). And I can see the dialog entering the screen, but tiny, without any text, arriving to the center of the screen, and only then becoming bigger with its content.

Somehow I need to tell the WebView to load its content BEFORE entering the screen.

Comment: I had a similar problem, switching to a `DialogFragment` removed the flicker.

Comment: You could build a custom dialog class, onCreate start an AysncTask which first show a ProgressBar  and load the url in the background, on postExecute hide the ProgressBar and show the WebView.

Comment: Have you tried calling builder.show()? I've used the builder multiple times and have never seen a flicker. The way I've always done them is using builder.show().

Comment: @user2045570: Sorry, I should have clarified this (updated now). The "page" is a local html in the assets. It is not a delay problem.

Comment: @Bobbake4: Tried, yes, with the same result.

Comment: @adneal: wow, a `DialogFragment` just to display a WebView sounds like a cannon. Your problem was with a WebView also?

Comment: I tried adding the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;`, but then I get a white background in the WebView (Why?).